# Set Checkbox when Radio button changes with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and I have an issue that has stumped me so far. I have spent a whole day on this with little progress.

I have 4 radio buttons that are bound to an observable called InvType:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdoAIP" name="rdoAIP" value="AIP" data-bind="checked: InvType" />AIP&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="rdoPSI" name="rdoPSI" value="PSI" data-bind="checked: InvType" />PSI&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="rdoPSIAIP" name="rdoPSIAIP" value="PSIAIP" data-bind="checked: InvType" />PSI/AIP&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="rdoShortForm" name="rdoShortForm" value="PSIShortForm" data-bind="checked: InvType" />PSI Short Form
```

I have several checkboxes that should only be checked when a specific radio button is checked:

```
<input data-bind="checked: OptionalValue1" id="chk1" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 1<br/>
<input data-bind="checked: OptionalValue2" id="chk2" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 2<br/>
<input data-bind="checked: OptionalValue2" id="chk3" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox 3<br/>
```

When the user clicks a different radio button, a different combination of check boxes should become checked as well. For example, if the "AIP" radio button is checked on initial page load, then the first 2 checkboxes should also be checked. But when the user clicks the "PSI" radio button, then I want only the first checkbox to be checked and the others should be unchecked.

edit:
Sorry but I was not clear about the check boxes. So here are the conditions:

1. On initial page load, the radio button gets set and this causes the checkboxes to update accordingly. Each different radio value cause a different combination of the checkboxes to become checked and  unchecked.
2. After the page loads, the user can click on an individual checkbox and change its value. This will NOT affect any other checkbox or radio button.

My knockout code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var psiInvestigationViewModel = @Html.Raw(New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));

    function PSIInvestigationViewModel(data) 
    {
        var self = this;
        InvestigationType : ko.observable();

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    };

$(function () 
{
    ko.applyBindings(new PSIInvestigationViewModel(psiInvestigationViewModel), $('#PSIInvestigation@(ViewData("UniqueID"))')[0]);

});
```

If someone could show me the code needed to get my checkboxes to update based on the radio button change, then I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Are the checkboxes readonly ?

Comment: no. the user can also change those "after the fact." Good catch!

Comment: So, after the user select a radio button the program should only preselect check boxes ?

Comment: Post updated accordingly to the  point 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all radio buttons should have the same, so if you select one the other will be deselected.

If the checkboxes are not readonly you can code the selection logic in an init function.
This init function will be called on each radio buttons change :

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.InvType = ko.observable();
    var initState = function () {
        var t = self.InvType();
        self.OptionalValue1(t == 'AIP' || t == 'PSIAIP');
        self.OptionalValue2(t == 'PSI' || t == 'PSIAIP');
        self.OptionalValue3(t == 'PSIAIP');
    };

    self.OptionalValue1 = ko.observable();
    self.OptionalValue2 = ko.observable();
    self.OptionalValue3 = ko.observable();
    self.InvType.subscribe(initState);
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8BAq/2/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: you nailed it! Thank you sir. Expect an extra large Christmas basket this season.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to use computed observables:

```
self.Optionalvalue1 = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.InvType() == 'AIP' || self.InvType() =='PSIAIP';
)};
```

and so on.